# Are questions about learning suitable for main?

Tags: discussion, scope

In [How do I learn which verb to use with an object?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/how-do-i-learn-which-verb-to-use-with-an-object), a user with a medium amount of rep asked why I asked it on meta, rather than main.

The closest thing I could get to an off-topic reason in [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se) was the answer [We don't do "how do I study X?" questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/798/91). The first paragraph of which is:

> We are focused on the language itself, not educational methods or
>   study systems. We'd rather not talk about flashcards vs
>   sentence-memorization. We are particularly harsh on "how do I keep
>   myself motivated?"-type questions, as these are well beyond the limits
>   of the language.

However, the paragraph seems to be talking about how to memorise a piece of information, or how to motivate yourself, and not about how to learn something.

Are questions about learning suitable for the main web site, or only meta and chat?

Related question: [Is the "learning" tag misleading?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/is-the-learning-tag-misleading)

Comment: I guess you're referring to my comment. I wrote that because honestly I don't know what is the answer to your question above. Your original question was for me in between: it was partly about the way you can learn some rules, partly about the rules themselves. +1 for asking this follow-up question and let's see what others say.

Comment: I think you can make the question perfectly valid on the main site by rephrasing some words like “how … learn” ...

Answer (score 1):

IMO, questions about learning and studying should be entirely suitable for this website. The purpose of an English language website dedicated to a foreign language can only be: to assist someone in learning that language. So if a website has that function, why not encourage questions about it? It's like turning up to a cooking class where they tell you all about how to bake cupcakes, but when you ask "How can I speed up my egg-whisking process?" or "How should I practice this recipe?" they say to you "Sorry, we don't deal with that here." People can ask about how to use language here, why not questions about how to study language?

Comment: I think I generally agree, but it is probably worth brainstorming what some example good questions would be, and have some advice for people on how to make questions of this type not be "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Okay. The thing that got me on this was when I asked 'Is it better to practice reading or writing the kana first?'. Possibly opinionated, but answerable I think, if there are studies to be found. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure. That sounds primarily opinion-based to me. I think there would need to be some significant text in the question body to suggest that you're looking for answers only based on objective evidence like large studies or similar.